# Поместить node_modules в другую директорию

Tags: node.js, webpack, npm

Поместить `node_modules` в другую директорию через `package.json` или другой конфиг, который можно разместить рядом. Настройка нужна без изменения окружения ОС. Требуемая структура:

```
|-app
|--service
|---node_modules
|--package.json
|--webpack.config.js
```

Необходим вариант использования по умолчанию `npm install` из директории `app`, после чего установка будет в директорию `app/service/node_modules`.

Например, в конфиге composer есть настройка для этого:

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "service/vendor"
  },
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Благодарю. Настройка нужна без изменения окружения ОС.

Comment: а какую проблему Вы таким образом пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в `app/service` находятся директории, которые не должны попадать в git (библиотеки, логи и т.п.). поэтому `app/service` в `.gitignore`. но конфиг npm (package.json, webpack.config.js) нужны в git, поэтому они вне директории `app/service`.

Comment: почему бы просто не заигнорить node_modules?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ разумеется можно. но в данном случае задача на оптимизацию.

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы иметь app/service в .gitignore и при этом иметь app/service/package.json в git

Comment: Более того, непонятно что мешает иметь app/node_modules? Все файлы из app/service отлично найдут свои зависимости и уровнем выше

Comment: Так node_modules автоматом в игнор ставиться. Не? О какой оптимизации речь?

Comment: @Дмытрык Суть в том, что все данные обслуживания сгруппировать в одной директории. А это не только `node_modules`, но и множество других (логи, библиотеки, кеш и т.п.). В этом случае достаточно контролировать игнор только одной директории, а не целого списка, актуальность которого придется поддерживать. Т.е. для любого обслуживания самого приложения: git (.gitignore), бекап, развертывание приложения боевое/тестовое/разработка, вынос директории за пределы приложения и т.п., достаточно взаимодействовать только с одной директорией, а не целым списком.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Конечно нет. Но то, что в `app/service`, например, не попадет в бекап. А значит это лишнее правило для обслуживания. Более развернуто см. выше.

Comment: Все равно, при данной диспозиции задачи, нет никакой необходимости в переносе папки node_modules

Comment: @Дмытрык Я Вас не понимаю, можете более развернуто почему нет?

Comment: Бэкап? Git? Зачем? Мне кажется вы пытаетесь решить несуществующую проблему. Одна строчка в gitignore это не целый список

Comment: @AlexeyTen в `.gitignore` сейчас именно одна строчка `app/service`. Именно в этом суть задачи, что бы не увеличивать зависимости игнора и не добавлять в него `app/service/package.json`.

Comment: Если положить package.json в git, то gitignore на него действовать не будет